# Prove order is invariant under analytic isomorphisms.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, function-and-relation-composition, meromorphic-functions

I have no idea where to even start this proof. Here is the theorem I have to prove:

> Let $f$ be meromorphic on an open set $U$. Let
>           $$\phi: V \rightarrow U$$
>           be an analytic isomorphism. Suppose $\phi(z_0) = w_0$, and $f$ has an order $n$ at $w_0$. Then, $f \circ \phi$ has order $n$ at $z_0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\phi$ takes every value in a nbd of $w_0$ $n$ times.

Comment: What do you mean by nbd?

Comment: @Birdman2246: neighbourhood.